# Get only those field names which are not null

Tags: apache-spark, struct, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe `df1`. Its `printSchema()` shows as below.

```
df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- parent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- childa: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- childb: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- childc: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- childd: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: string (nullable = true)
```

```
df1.show(10,False)

----------------------------------------------------------------
|parent                                                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|[,[x_value, y_value, z_value], ,[x_value, y_value, z_value]]  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `df1.show()` shows that childb and childd are not null.

1. I am able get all the child struct field names like (childa, childb, childc, childd).
2. And also I want to get only those child struct field names which are not null.

The below approach is giving me all the child struct field names into a list, which answered my above first requirement.

```
spark.sql("""select parent.* from df1""").schema.fieldNames()
Output:
[childa, childb, childc, childd]
```

Now I want to get only those child struct field names which are not null.
I am expecting only childb and childd into a list.

Expected Output: `[childb, childd]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do check whether the fields are null using a filter and count:

```
non_null_fields = [
    field
    for field in df.select('parent.*').schema.fieldNames()
    if df.filter('parent.%s is null' % field).count() == 0
]
```

which gives

```
['childb', 'childd']
```

Comment: ```I am using Spark version 2.4.0. Getting the syntax error.

Comment: can I have this ['childb','childd'] into my original dataframe df1 as a separate column with column name non_null_fields

Comment: @Sri you can use `df1.withColumn('non_null_fields', F.array(*[F.lit(f) for f in non_null_fields]))`

Comment: ```df1.withColumn('non_null_fields', F.array(*[F.lit(f) for f in non_null_fields]))``` Here if you see non_null_fields is a List which is passed as a input to the withColumn. But I want to pass the dataframe column itself as a argument. can we do that.

Comment: something like this ```df1.withColumn('non_null_fields', F.array(*[F.lit(f) for f in df1.col(non_null_fields)]))```

Comment: @Sri then you can try `df1.withColumn('non_null_fields', F.array(*[F.col(f) for f in non_null_fields]))`

Comment: I agree but, but I want to read the df1 column directly please.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve... could you elaborate please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228543/discussion-between-sri-and-mck).